# Regularity of heat equation with nonhomogeneous boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider the heat equation

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
u_{t} - \Delta u = f &\text{in }(0,T)\times\Omega\\ u(x,t) = g(x,t) &(t,x)\in [0,T]\times\partial\Omega\\ u(x,0) = h(x) &\text{on }\{0\}\times\Omega.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

When $g(t) = 0$, we have the estimate from Evans:

\begin{aligned}
\text{ess sup}_{0 \leqslant t \leqslant T} \|u(t)\|_{H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)} + \|u\|_{L^{2}(0,T;H^{2}(\Omega))} + \|u'\|_{L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))} \leqslant C(\|f\|_{L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))} + \|h\|_{H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)}).
\end{aligned}

I am curious about the case when $g\neq 0$ and wondering if anyone has a reference they can point me to. I know in the case of the Poisson equation, the boundary data would appear in the estimate taken in a trace space such $H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)$. Would it be similar here?

**Edit:** I've added a sketch of my solution attempt. My idea was to try to leverage the existing estimate. Namely, consider $u_g \in L^{2}(0,T; H^{2}(\Omega))$ with $u_{g}' \in L^{2}(0,T; L^{2}(\Omega))$ which satisfies, for fixed $t$, $\mathfrak{T}u_g(\cdot,t) = g(\cdot,t)$, where $\mathfrak{T} : H^{2}(\Omega) \to H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)$ is the trace operator. When $\Omega$ is Lipschitz I believe $\mathfrak{T}$ should have a continuous right inverse. Setting $\tilde{u} := u - u_g$, we have

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\tilde{u}_{t} - \Delta \tilde{u} = f - (u_g)_t + \Delta u_g &\text{in }(0,T)\times\Omega\\ \tilde{u}(x,t) = 0 &(t,x)\in [0,T]\times\partial\Omega\\ \tilde{u}(x,0) = h(x) &\text{on }\{0\}\times\Omega.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

if $u_g(x,0) = 0$ as well. Applying Evans' estimate gives

\begin{aligned}
\text{ess sup}_{0 \leqslant t \leqslant T} \|\tilde{u}(t)\|_{H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)} + \|\tilde{u}\|_{L^{2}(0,T;H^{2}(\Omega))} + \|\tilde{u}'\|_{L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))} &\leqslant C(\|f\|_{L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))} + \|\Delta u_g\|_{L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))} + \|u_g'\|_{L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))} + \|h\|_{H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)})\\
&\leqslant C(\|f\|_{L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))} + \|u_g\|_{L^{2}(0,T; H^{2}(\Omega))} + \|u_g'\|_{L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))} + \|h\|_{H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)})\\
&\leqslant C(\|f\|_{L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))} + \|g\|_{L^{2}(0,T; H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega))} + \|u_g'\|_{L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))} + \|h\|_{H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)}).
\end{aligned}

I thought I could use this estimate along with a triangle inequality to obtain the estimates on $u$, but the term $\|u_g'\|_{L^{2}(0,T; L^{2}(\Omega))}$ is giving me some pause. Maybe I could define it so that $u_g'(t) = 0$ in a region away from $t=0$ and the boundaries and then have to vary to 0 in a way that still preserves $u_g(\cdot,t) \in H^{2}(\Omega)$, but I'm having trouble with this part and what the estimate would look like.

**Final edit:** For anyone who comes across this question in the future, I found two very useful texts that discuss spaces for the boundary data and trace theorems for the space $H^{s}(0,T; H^{2s}(\Omega))$. These are

[Optimal Lp-Lq estimates for parabolic boundary value problems with inhomogeneous data](https://kops.uni-konstanz.de/entities/publication/b81c5571-5655-4de3-91dc-6689a8dd85f8) (Denk, Hieber, and Prüss)

[Nonhomogeneous boundary value problems and applications](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65217-2) (Lions and Magene)

Comment: Can you briefly sketch the proof of that inequality from Evans? I guess what you conjecture is right and possibly it is an easy consequence of that inequality, or a minor modification of its proof.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I spent some time thinking on it and have added an attempt at a solution that uses the original estimate, but was stuck at one point estimating a new term involving time derivatives. I added my attempt to the original post.